# How can I add that my code checks a third person instead of user and admin as shown

Tags: php, mysql

In the piece of code I will show it will check on my database weather or not user is a admin or a user. I want to add premium for premium users.

I tried the || and a diffrent else statement. I have searched it up and cannot fix it. Please help me as I really need help with this.

This right now is the code it is at currenlty

```
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
                // check if user is admin or user
                $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                    header('location: admin/home.php');       
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                    header('location: index.php');
                }
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried

```
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
                // check if user is admin or user
                $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin' || 'prem') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                    header('location: admin/home.php');       
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                    header('location: index.php');
                }

// a else statement goes here I forgot what I put but it was simalr to lines above.
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I enter it. The output should be my page. The output is really just Saying that sad error face. ERROR HTTP 500. Then Reload.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand on what you already have by adding a separate else loop that checks for the 'premium' user type. (see below)

```
if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
   $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
   exit(header("Location: admin/home.php");     
} elseif ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'prem') {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
   $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
   exit(header("Location: premiumindex.php");
} else {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
   $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
   exit(header("Location: userindex.php");
}
```

*Note:  I added `session_start();` to your loops to initiate session handling. Also, I was taught to write a header redirect as: `exit(header("Location: page");`*